# Django 2.1, How to show Foreign key values in template?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Sorry for my English level and my model is not good.

Now, i'm stuck showing value in templates.

**purchaseinfo/models.py**

```
class Status(Models.model):         
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class PurchaseInfo(models.Model):
    purchase_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    .....
    type = models.ForeignKey(Status,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**customlogin/views.py**

```
def purchaseHistory(request):
    history = PurchaseInfo.objects.filter(purchase_id=request.user).values()
    return render(request,'customlogin/purchaseHistory.html',{'history':history})
```

**customlogin/purchaseHistory.html**

```
{% for i in history %}
<tr>
    <td>{{i.purchase_name}}</td>
    <td>{{i.product_price}}</td>
    ......
    <td>{{i.type}}</td>   <---- Here, Only this cannot show
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In templates, Other things work well. But **{{i.type}}** cannot show.

class Status's values : before deposit, Confirmation of payment and so on.

**before deposit** is base value. So i want to show base value in templates.

How can show the {{i.type}} in templates?? T.T

Comment: Can you please share the fields ("before deposit", etc.) in the `Status` model?

Comment: What do you mean, "cannot show"? Do you mean you see nothing at all, or what?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, before deposit, Confirmation of payment, shipping, 
Delivery completed, Receipt confirmation

Comment: @Daniel Roseman , Yes, nothing at all. {{i.type}} --> "  "

Comment: Did you set your __str__ method on the Status Model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: note the `.values()` at the end, therefore it will not "resolve" the FK.

Comment: @Carl Brubaker, what is str method ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah I'm seeing a lot of questions lately where people are using `values()` unnecessarily. I wonder if there's a book or blog somewhere that's recommended it.

Comment: Add {{ i.type.type }}

Comment: `The __str__` method of a model is what is displayed when you call an object.

Comment: @Carl Brubaker, def __str__(self): return self.type . Thanks for your comment !. But Willem Van Onsem solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you call the `QuerySet` with `.values()` at the end, and therefore you will obtain a `QuerySet` of dictionaries. Foreign keys are *not* resolved, but you fetch the corresponding primary key.

It is better to use `.values()` only when you really need it: when you want to fetch a subset of columns. Normally it is better to fetch model objects, since then the "behavior" you attached to the objects remains the same.

```
def purchaseHistory(request):
    # no .values()
    history = PurchaseInfo.objects.filter(purchase_id=request.user)
    return render(request,'customlogin/purchaseHistory.html',{'history':history})
```

Now that we have made a `QuerySet` of `PurchaseInfo` objects, in the template, `i.type` will be `Status` object. This will render the `Status` object, by calling the `str(..)` object. By default this will look like `Status object (123)` with `123`

You can however access fields from this `Status` object in the template as well:

```
{% for i in history %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ i.purchase_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.product_price }}</td>
    ......
    <td>{{ i.type.type }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

given the name of the field is `type`, so if that field contains as value `'Before deposit'`, it will render that string.

Since we here will fetch the related `Status` object for *each* `PurchaseInfo` object in the queryset, it is better to fetch it in one query, like:

```
def purchaseHistory(request):
    # no .values()
    history = PurchaseInfo.objects.filter(purchase_id=request.user).select_related('type')
    return render(request,'customlogin/purchaseHistory.html',{'history':history})
```

You might want to override the `__str__` method in the `Status` class, such that this is the "standard" way of rendering the status, like:

```
class Status(Models.model):         
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

In that case `{{ i.type }}` in the template will suffice.

Comment: Thanky you sincerely!. T.T...
My English is not very good. Thank you for understanding.